# Getting High Resolution Images from Google Image Search

Tags: c#, image, webclient

Am using this code

```
  List<string> ImageList = GetAllImages(Searchname);

   public static List<string> GetAllImages(string file)
   {
       List<string> ImageList = new List<string>();
       WebClient x = new WebClient();


       HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
       string source = x.DownloadString(file);
       document.LoadHtml(source);

       foreach (var link in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
           .Select(i => i.Attributes["src"]))
       {
           ImageList.Add(link.Value);
       }
       return ImageList;
   }
```

I am putting searches of Images of Bands like Status Quo Albums into Google Images Search

```
 string GoogleSearch = @"https://www.google.com/search?q=";
```

```
//Full Colour Large Image
//From Google Advanced Search webpage
string GoogleMiddle = "&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwizlL6W6sLxAhUE_4UKHS_YBDEQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=";

string GoogleEnding = "&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BwgAELEDEEM6BAgAEENQ3I8FWJ6YBWDsnQVoAHAAeACAAasCiAHYCZIBAzItNZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=bjXeYLOlJ4T-lwSvsJOIAw&bih=802&biw=1707&pli=1";

 Searchname = GoogleSearch + "Status Quo Albums" + GoogleMiddle + GoogleEnding;


                  
 List<string> ImageList = GetAllImages(Searchname);
```

Instead of Get Large Images,
I am getting Small Low Resolutions Images

Does anyone know to obtain Large High Resolution Images from Google Image Search

Comment: Rule #1 for downloading stuff off the internet is scraping (reading a web page, parsing it and download files from it), is almost always the wrong way to do it.   Use the Google API and you will have full control of downloading different resolution files.